# CSS transform scale on react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have a image in react native

```
<Image source={backgroundPinguimKing} style={styles.imagebackgroundPinguim} />
```

I want my image to grow from 50px to 250px and stay in 250. In pure css i know that exist transform: scale() but how can i do that in react native?

Comment: hi, perhaps try specifying a `width` or `height` for the displayed image. you might be interested in [`resizeMethod`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemethod-android) too..

Comment: style={{transform: [{scale: 5}]}}

Comment: It worked, thanks you both! o/